# Is there an efficient method to storing table headers in a VBA Collection?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to store each of my Tables Header values in a `Collection`. The code I am using does just that but, it seems like my `Collection` is duplicating items. I believe this has to do with the way I am adding the header values in my `Collection`. I am facing a

> Runtime Error 13

when trying to retrieve `Collection` items in a `For Each` loop

**Code**

```
Public Property Get TmProducts() As Collection
    Set TmProducts = this.TmProducts
    TmProducts.Add TmTable.ListObjects("Table1").HeaderRowRange.value
End Property
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're assigning the array of header values to the first item in your collection.  As such, you would need to loop through each item in your array as follows...

```
Dim item As Variant
For Each item In TmProducts(1)
    Debug.Print item
Next item
```

However, since you probably want to assign each header value to a separate item in your collection, you'll need to assign them as follows...

```
Dim currentCell As Range
For Each currentCell In TmTable.ListObjects("Table1").HeaderRowRange
    TmProducts.Add currentCell.Value
Next currentCell
```

Then you can access the items in your collection as follows...

```
Dim item As Variant
For Each item In TmProducts
    Debug.Print item
Next item
```

Comment: So you mean to tell me i can have an `Item(item)` and call it by using `TmProducts(2)`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but in your original code you're assigning the array of values to the first item in the collection.  You haven't assigned any other values or arrays to the collection.  So it only has a single item, the array, no other items.